# WCF Operation Time out Exception

Tags: c#, wcf

When I try to call Test WCF method I get OperationTimeOut exception.
When I set Test method's IsOneWay to true it works fine but when I remove it
I geting   exception.Without Debug program works fine

Service

```
public class SyncService : ISyncContract
{
    STOREDBEntities db = STOREDBEntitiesSingleTon.Instance;
    public virtual void Test()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Test");
    }

}
```

And Contract

```
public interface ISyncContract
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOnWay=false)]
        void Test();
    }
```

Server Code

```
void StartServer()
    {
        Uri address = new Uri($"http://{Ip}:{Port}/Sync");

        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();

        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;

        Type contract = typeof(ISyncContract);

        host = new ServiceHost(service);

        host.AddServiceEndpoint(contract, binding, address);

        try
        {
            host.Open();
            Log += $"Server Started At {DateTime.Now}";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Client Code

```
 void ConnectToServer()
    {
        Uri address = new Uri($"http://{Ip}:{port}/Sync");
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(address);

        ChannelFactory<ISyncContract> factory = new ChannelFactory<ISyncContract>(binding, endpoint);
        try
        {
            channel = factory.CreateChannel();
            channel.Test();
            IsConnectedWithServer = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Successfully Connected!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Screenshot in fiddler
[image]

Can someone explain why i getting exception and how to solve it for methods with returning value

Comment: OneWay operations don't wait for server replay that is cause.

Comment: Why my server doesn't replay

Comment: You should change the timeout config in server side in `web.config` , to config theme right, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/configuring-timeout-values-on-a-binding)

Comment: add your service configuration to be more clear question.

Comment: I changed the timeout to 10 but I get same exception.Too.I updated question

Comment: So set the breakpoint in `Test()` in server, be sure when you run client  the Test method get fired or not in server-side?

Comment: No it not get fired in server-side but if i setting (IsOnWay=true) it's get fired